# SCRIPT5009: 'search' is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to invoke a function when the user moves the mouse out of the input field.

```
<input #filter onmouseout="search(filter.value)">
```

the function:

```
  search(term: string): void {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.employeeFirstName.length; i ++) {
      if(this.employeeFirstName[i] != term) {
        this.employeeFirstName[i] = this.employeeFirstName[i + 1]
      }
      else {
        this.employeeFirstName[i + 1] = this.employeeFirstName[i]
      }
    }
  }
```

But when I am testing it give me the error:

> SCRIPT5009: 'search' is not defined

can someone explain why this error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

try 
(mouseout)="search(filter.value)"
the code which you have written is checking for java script function instead of angular

Comment: <input #filter (mouseout)="search(filter.value)">

Comment: Thanks that helped, however now when I try to test this after mouseover the browser crashes.

Comment: It seems like you are calling that function over and over.

Comment: but when I am testing I am reloading the browser

Comment: Alto tried clearing the cash but it won't work, It have been working some time but suddenly the page crashes after I invoke the function

Comment: why do you want mouse out for input field? you search logic calls infinite times if it goes to else condition at final iteration

Comment: I am trying to sort an array based on the user input, so when the user enters enters the string the array would sort and the string in the array that is equal to his entry would come on top off the array

Comment: why (mouseout)  you can use (change) happens once if the input changes as per code `let a=[]; onitemAdd(item){a=[item].concat(a)}` in this way the changed value will be on the top of the array and all the new values will be at start

Comment: But I am not trying to add to the array just want to sort an array that exists already

Comment: search(term: string) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.employeeFirstName.length; i ++) {
          if(this.employeeFirstName[i] != term) {
            var swap = this.employeeFirstName[i];
            this.employeeFirstName[i] = this.employeeFirstName[i + 1];
            this.employeeFirstName[i + 1] = swap;
          }
        }
      }

Comment: for autocomplete ? check [link](https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c)

Comment: Thanks a lot, what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular2+ (it seems like you are using typescript, so I guess you are using angular2+) then you need to take onmouseout within braces